# BigQuery denormalization advice for JSON arrays (one-to-many)

Tags: json, google-bigquery, denormalization

I am trying to create a schema for a huge JSON dataset. The data is already in the denormalized form (I got it like this from a 3rd party). One issue I am facing now is that the denormalized JSON features arrays of strings (and sometimes objects) which translates to one-to-many relationship between classic SQL tables. This is something BQ does not recognize.

Does finding arrays implies that each such array needs to be placed in a table of its own?

I've created a simple example:

```
 { "name": "John Doe", "books_read": [ "Jungle Book", "Cinderella", "Harry Potter", "The Little Prince" ] }
```

Is there a good schema for this sample data other than creating two tables `users` and `books_read` and linking them?

I am so focused on denormalization that creating more than one table feels like going against BQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BigQuery supports nested and structured data (same model as JSON), it would be the best to model it as single table with following schema:

```
STRING name
REPEATED STRING books_read
```

BigQuery's SQL dialect has plenty of support to work with such repeated structures.

Comment: Sounds great! How about repeated records? Is that supported too?

Comment: Of course - here is the data type reference for BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes, RECORD is included.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Tested it myself in the meantime. Works great! Loving it.